# Querying _Job data view

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to query _Job data view from my top level account. It retrieved the rows belonging to top level account only (unlike other views)

Other views (_Sent, _Click etc.) - they return the data of all the business units.

Is this a know constraint of _Job view? Or should I reach out to SFMC Support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, this is a constraint of the _JOB data view.  Since jobs are account level objects, you'll only see jobs that were created in the account that you're querying them under.

When it comes to _Click, _Sent, _Bounce, etc., these are subscriber level activities.  In an Enterprise 2.0 account, subscribers are stored on the All Subscriber's list, which is owned by the top level account.  Any of the above activities will be recorded against this unique subscriber record.  This gives you the ability to query against these activities across other "OYBAccountID" (Business Units) from the top level Enterprise Account.

You can see within each of those data views that the field name, "OYBAccountID", is available for you to view and narrow down your query results as needed.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremy! That helped and at the same time poses another challenge for my project 

Comment: How can I get the email subject and email name of a Send Job?

Comment: You might be able to explore the use of Send Logging.  You would have the ability to use send logging for all non-send-definition sends in an enterprise account.  This also allows all BUs to utilize a single SendLog placed in the shared folder that you can then also add/pass email name and subject to your send log.    
https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/

Comment: Send Logging DE can be used only with User Initiated or Triggered Send which might not be the case always. I am building an email analytics system outside of SFMC, so need all the emails

Comment: If you request SFMC to enable ENT.AUTO, it will automatically log those that are not Triggered or User Initiated Sends.  Query activities in the Business Units that populate a shared DE might also be an option but cumbersome.

Comment: Hi Jeremy - Guess what I did? I created a tracking extract in the top level BU and selected only 3 boxes (SendJob, Sent, SendJobImression) and it gave me the Jobs from all across :) 

I wonder that why query is not possible from the top account and tracking extract is :)